# "npm audit fix" will install a deprecated package

Tags: node.js, npm, audit, npm-vulnerabilities

When I run **npm audit** it tells me the following about vulnerabilities:

```
react-dev-utils  0.4.0 - 12.0.0-next.60
Severity: critical
Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an OS Command. - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5q6m-3h65-w53x
Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
Depends on vulnerable versions of fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
Depends on vulnerable versions of globby
Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
Depends on vulnerable versions of inquirer
Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @sambego/storybook-state@1.3.6, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@sambego/storybook-state/node_modules/react-dev-utils
node_modules/react-dev-utils
```

It says **npm fix** will install

--> @sambego/storybook-state@1.3.6,

but in my package.json it says

--> "@sambego/storybook-state": "^2.0.1",

So my package is much newer than the recommended package.

**I will accept any answer that tells me if and why I can ignore this critical npm vulnerability.**

Comment: this is also case for me. When I try to see fix for audit issues it shows to install testcafe@15.1.317922, which is published 5 years ago

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for me as well. If you see the below image, fix suggests to install an outdated version of testcafe.

[image]

Same thing happens codelyzer as well, It is complaining about angular version and suggests to install codelyzer@0.0.28 instead of the version 6.x.x which is used in project

[image]

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe/v/15.1.317922